# The application failed to initialize properly 0xc0150002

Tags: .net, windows-7, exception, windows-xp

This error is faced by many people, but still I am unable to get the proper solution.  I tried many suggestion in forum, but with no help.

I developed an application on VS 2010. The application is  a winform application and uses OpenCV library for doing some simple image processing tasks.
Initially I did the entire development on Windows 7. Now I am shifting to windows XP.

I copy the entire project folder from windows 7 machine and pasted in xp machine.  Then I started the solution file .sln from this project folder. The file opens fine and compiles without any issues. But when I am running the exe it is giving the following error:

> The application failed to initialize properly 0xc0150002....

I tried both in release mode and debug mode but, I am facing the same problem.

My guess is in the background some OS specific changes have occurred when I was developing on windows 7, and now those changes are incompatible with windows xp.

I shall really appreciate if somebody can point me to some hint to solve this issue.

**Update:**
In the event log I could not find the application, but one error  that is visible and shown with red ! is :

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime Optimization Service
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1103
Date:       9/18/2012
Time:       2:40:51 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MAYA-ACMTTE
Description:
.NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32) - Tried to start a    
service that wasn't the latest version of CLR Optimization service. Will shutdown
```

This error came when I installed .net framework 3.5 (in addition to 4.0 which was already installed)

Comment: do you need to run your program in another pc with win7 os?

Comment: no actually I have to compile and run in another xp machine (the program was written and compiled successfully in windows 7)

Comment: There's little reason to assume your case is special.  The same troubleshooting strategy certainly applies, look in the event log for the error.  It will tell you that a DLL could not be found, install the proper DLL.

Comment: @HansPassan I am sorry could you please tell me where do I get this event log file? Are you talking about output window that appears during build process?

Comment: The Windows event log.  Control Panel + Administrative Tools + Event viewer.  Look at the Application event log for the error.

Comment: That's not the right one.  If you can't find the error then there's no good way to help you.

Answer (score 3):

i think it is a dll files problem, first of all you must install windows installer on win xp and install framework 3.5. or you must switch your application to release mode and in the solution explorer window click show all and under myproject check all checkboxes and run your application then go to release folder and copy this folder to xp os and try it

Comment: I am not trying to port an  exe. I am just  compiling and running on windows XP.  I have already compiled and run on windows 7.

Comment: man! i know that you want to compile at xp only, but since you develop your application under win7, your application use win7 dlls that's are  dlls in framework 3.5, that's why you need to copy dlls of win7 to xp. i'm sure this is your problem because i face it before and i solve it by this way

Comment: Thanks, but my windows 7 system is not booting now :-(

Comment: here's something that will tell you the dll's used in a program: http://www.dependencywalker.com/